# How to change every nvarchar column to varchar?

Tags: sql-server-2005

what would be the simplest way to change every nvarchar column in a database to a varchar?

I personally would prefer nvarchar, but the data arch has specified that varchar must be used.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here, to get you started:

```
Select 'Alter Table [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] Alter Column [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] VarChar(' + CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH As VARCHAR) + ')'
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'NVARCHAR'
```

This will generate all the needed alter statements for you (cut, paste, run).

Note that this does not take any constraints into account.

Comment: +1 perfect. I got the same solution... but with a very very ugly and complicated query ...

Comment: @Jonathan How do I use the code in this answer to "generate all the needed alter statements" in SSQL Management Studio so that I can "cut, paste, run" ?

Comment: @emmanuel: 1) run this query; 2) go to the results window and cut the text (if your results window looks like a grid rather than just text, hit Ctrl-T, then run it again), 3) open up a new query window, paste in the results, make sure you are in the correct database and execute.

Comment: If you feel really fun, you could string this together and run it w/ some dynamic sql, but then a single nvarchar primary key or other constraint will break it, likely making it less practical.

Comment: Frankly, if you have nvarchar primary keys you deserve bad things happening to you :-)

Answer (score 6):

In order to handle MAX and exclude the niggly sysdiagrams:

```
SELECT 
'
ALTER TABLE [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] 
ALTER COLUMN [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] 
VARCHAR(' + 
    (CASE WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1 
        THEN 'MAX' 
        ELSE CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR) 
    END)
 + ')
'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'NVARCHAR' AND TABLE_NAME <> 'SYSDIAGRAMS'
```

Answer (score 3):

Ask the data arch to do it?

or

Generate a script of all objects in your system, alter then nvarchar's, then create a new database and import the data into it from the old one.

or

Write alter scripts to update the existing database.
(This may be the best approach if it's a production database, or a client database.)

Comment: Seconding "ask the data arch to do it".

Comment: Don't forget to check first to see if you have any data that won't convert to varchar.

I agree if the data architect wants this, it's up to him to write the scripts to do it.