# Password hashing used to work, now I can't get into my software

Tags: c#, sql, hash

I salted and hashed my logins [according to this Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/608860/Understanding-and-Implementing-Password-Hashing)

When I did this, my password and salt fields in the database were just varchar columns. The data was displayed in SQL Server Management Studio as question marks.

A friend then came and changed the columns to nvarchar data type and now the data appears to be a collection of Asian letters/words - I assume there's no sense behind it even to someone who does read whatever language it is.

The problem is that now, even when I created a new user, every login attempt fails.

**User addition and login**

```
    public User Login() // returns an instance of its own class
    {

        // get the salt value for the user
        var auser = ie.users.FirstOrDefault(u => String.Compare(u.emailaddress, emailaddress, false) == 0);
        if (auser == null)
        {
            throw new ValidationException("User not found");
        }

        // hash the login for comparison to stored password hash
        HashGenerator h = new HashGenerator(password, auser.usersalt);
        string hash = h.GetHash();

        var us = ie.users.FirstOrDefault(u => String.Compare(u.emailaddress, emailaddress, false) == 0 && String.Compare(u.password, password, false) == 0);

        if (us == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid email address and/or password."); // seems here's where it goes wrong
        }
        User user = new User();

        user.userid = us.userid;
        user.storeid = us.storeid;
        user.role = us.role;

        return user; // login succeeded, return the data to the calling method
    }

    public void Add()
    {
        user newuser = new user();
        newuser.storeid = storeid;
        newuser.emailaddress = emailaddress;

        // Generate password hash
        string usersalt = SaltGenerator.GetSaltString();
        HashGenerator hash = new HashGenerator(password, usersalt);
        newuser.password = hash.GetHash();

        newuser.role = role;
        newuser.usersalt = usersalt;

        ie.users.Add(newuser);
        ie.SaveChanges();
    }
```

**Hash and Salt Generator**

```
public class HashGenerator
{
    public string pass { get; protected set; }
    public string salt { get; protected set; }

    public HashGenerator(string Password, string Salt)
    {
        pass = Password;
        salt = Salt;
    }

    public string GetHash()
    {
        SHA512 sha = new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] data = CryptUtility.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}{1}", pass, salt));
        byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(data);

        return CryptUtility.GetString(hash);
    }
}

public static class SaltGenerator
{
    private static RNGCryptoServiceProvider provider = null;
    private const int saltSize = 128;

    static SaltGenerator()
    {
        provider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    }

    public static string GetSaltString()
    {
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[saltSize];

        provider.GetNonZeroBytes(saltBytes);

        return CryptUtility.GetString(saltBytes);
    }
}
```

**Crypt utility for getting strings and bytes**

```
class CryptUtility
{
    public static byte[] GetBytes(string Str)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[Str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(Str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }

    public static string GetString(byte[] Bytes)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[Bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(Bytes, 0, chars, 0, Bytes.Length);
        return new string(chars);
    }
}
```

The login used to work and this code hasn't changed since then... The only thing that's changed is that the password and salt columns in the users table are now `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`.

That said, I figured I'd create a new user with the add method above, but logging in with that user fails as well.

I'm really at a loss as to how to fix this. I can't proceed to develop the rest of the system if I can't access it to test.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try changing the columns back to `varchar`?

Comment: converting back gives a warning about possible data loss so no

Comment: Make a copy of the database, do the conversion back to `varchar` and see if it works.  There very well might be data loss, but the whole effort should be pretty quick and might just work.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1842571/745969) might help in converting the columns back; not sure about data loss in existing rows though.  Since the original data was `varchar`, I'd expect very little to no data loss going back to it; if you have unicode data in there then you will have trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

humm shouldn't you be using the variable

> hash

for the comparison ?

```
    // hash the login for comparison to stored password hash
    HashGenerator h = new HashGenerator(password, auser.usersalt);
    string hash = h.GetHash();

    var us = ie.users.FirstOrDefault(u => String.Compare(u.emailaddress, emailaddress, false) == 0 && String.Compare(u.password, hash, false) == 0);
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer because that's probably what went wrong. I have since moved to this instead... https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#aspsourcecode

Answer (score 0):

Make a db backup and convert back to varchar. Or rollback to the backup before the conversion. It seems your friend did something wrong when converting the data type to nvarchar.

Comment: I backed up the database and changed back to varchar. Still can't login

Comment: Ask your friend what he did and if he made a backup before his change. Maybe the char set of db should be changed.

Comment: I saw what he did... He'd remoted into my system with teamviewer while we were discussing my system on a skype call

Comment: You need the implementation of getnonzerobytes to see how the type depends on the db data type. And how did he convert the columns? It seems he lost some data there

Comment: If he lost data (not saying he didn't), why can't I log in with a user I created after he made the change? Got anymore info for me on getnonzerobytes for me?