# Byte values for login are different between user input and stored data

Tags: c#, hash, byte

History: [Password hashing used to work, now I can't get into my software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23591723/password-hashing-used-to-work-now-i-cant-get-into-my-software)

Since writing the question above (basically, just can't log in and didn't know why), I've determined that the byte arrays for the password I entered when I logged in and the password I entered when I created the user record, are completely different:

[Here's the bytes from the database](http://pastebin.com/z2vWfX0J)
[Here's the bytes from the password when I failed to logged in](http://pastebin.com/WLy4iyTW)

Now that I know that the value being passed to the database (or the value stored in the database) are wrong, I'm at a loss as to how I should fix it...

I'm not even sure why this used to work, but suddenly broke.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

Here's the user login and registration code

```
    public User Login() // returns an instance of its own class
    {
        var auser = ie.users.FirstOrDefault(u => String.Compare(u.emailaddress, emailaddress, false) == 0);

        if (auser == null)
        {
            throw new ValidationException("User not found");
        }

        // get bytes for password in the database
        byte[] passwordbytes = CryptUtility.GetBytes(auser.password);

        HashGenerator h = new HashGenerator(password, auser.usersalt);
        string hash = h.GetHash();

        var us = ie.users.FirstOrDefault(u => String.Compare(u.emailaddress, emailaddress, false) == 0 && String.Compare(u.password, password, false) == 0);

        if (us == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid email address and/or password.");
        }
        User user = new User();

        user.userid = us.userid;
        user.storeid = us.storeid;
        user.role = us.role;

        return user;
    }

    public void Add() // user registration
    {
        user newuser = new user();
        newuser.storeid = storeid;
        newuser.emailaddress = emailaddress;

        // Generate password hash
        string usersalt = SaltGenerator.GetSaltString();
        HashGenerator hash = new HashGenerator(password, usersalt);
        newuser.password = hash.GetHash();

        newuser.role = role;
        newuser.usersalt = usersalt;

        ie.users.Add(newuser);
        ie.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Here's the security code to generate hash and salt values and their byte/string values as well

```
public class HashGenerator
{
    public string pass { get; protected set; }
    public string salt { get; protected set; }

    public HashGenerator(string Password, string Salt)
    {
        pass = Password;
        salt = Salt;
    }

    public string GetHash()
    {
        SHA512 sha = new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] data = CryptUtility.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}{1}", pass, salt));
        byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(data);

        return CryptUtility.GetString(hash);
    }
}

public static class SaltGenerator
{
    private static RNGCryptoServiceProvider provider = null;
    private const int saltSize = 128;

    static SaltGenerator()
    {
        provider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    }

    public static string GetSaltString()
    {
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[saltSize];

        provider.GetNonZeroBytes(saltBytes);

        return CryptUtility.GetString(saltBytes);
    }
}

class CryptUtility
{
    public static byte[] GetBytes(string Str)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[Str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(Str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }

    public static string GetString(byte[] Bytes)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[Bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(Bytes, 0, chars, 0, Bytes.Length);
        return new string(chars);
    }
}
```

Comment: We need more details, add your code for login and registering.

Comment: I would guess that the lib that you use for it should have changed! But you need to support more info on how you do it.

Comment: @BertrandC. added the code for ya

Comment: @Ortund Likely unrelated, but please, don't use those `GetBytes` and `GetString` methods! It's a dirty hack, not a reliable way to convert char array to byte array and back. *Always* use an encoding - e.g. `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` and `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` respectively. There's many ways the same unicode string can be represented in memory (little endian vs. big endian being one possible issue, unicode normalization another, there's chars longer than `sizeof(char)` etc.) - your code relies on `byte[]` equality, so don't *guess* that it will be always the same - use proper encoding.

Comment: @Ortund Oh, and now that I'm looking more closely, scratch that  "likely unrelated" part. Given the amount of `GetBytes` + `GetString` you're doing, it's very likely you've ended up with invalid unicode strings at some point. `string` is *not* a byte array. Joel Spolsky has a great article on the topic - http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @Luaan thanks for the tips, so rather than that, I'm running it through `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` and `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've pretty much said everything in the comments, but looking at your other question and such, I feel I have to post this as an answer, because it's absolutely the solution to your problem.

Unicode is a complicated charset (http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html - do read it). The important thing you have to realize that there's no 1:1 mapping between a unicode string and a byte array. One char can have a single byte, or it can have many more. More importantly, there's a lot of magic chars, so "casting" a general byte array to a string can very easily result in an invalid unicode string, or it can malform your data!

This is why it worked for you when your column was `varchar`. In `varchar`, every char has a 1:1 mapping to a byte, as simple as that. So "casting" a byte array to a `varchar` and back doesn't lead to data changes or data loss. This no longer applies for `nvarchar`, because `nvarchar` is a unicode string (just like .NETs `string`).

Instead, save the password hash as a byte array (`binary` or `varbinary`), or, convert the byte array to a Base-64 string - that's the commonly used pattern when you need both plain-text and hashed password for example. So your `GetBytes()` would be doing `Convert.FromBase64String`, and `GetString` would be doing `Convert.ToBase64String`.